# Vue-router will not load the correct component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Using vue-router, it keeps throwing me back to the initial component I have routed to `/`

Router is initialized as such:

```
export default new Router({
  history: true,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'BodyParent',
      component: BodyParent
    },
    {
      path: '/configuration',
      name: 'Configuration',
      component: Configuration
    }
  ]
})
```

If I go to `/configuration`, it will still load the `BodyParent` component, but the browser URL will go to `/configuration` initially, then to `/configuration#/` while still loading `BodyParent`

If I put the `Configuration` component to route to /, it does render it. How come?

So the problem is pretty generic - Vue router defaults to the component that is set to `/`

Comment: Well its `mode: 'history'` not `history: true` if you want history mode on

Comment: Well no, that throws an error in the console

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I was using a regular `href` to navigate.

I should have used: `<router-link to="Configuration">Config</router-link>`